# Are LED Panels/Lightboxes intended for "animation" usable for photographic purposes?

Tags: lighting, color

LED Panels that are described as intended for animation drawing tend to be a quarter of the price of such panels that are explicitly intended for photography work (macro lighting, slide viewing and copying etc.)

Do these cheaper panels tend to have drawbacks that make them ill suited for photography purposes, eg PWM dimmers that candy stripe on sensors, uneven lighting, or horribly bad CRI in practice? Or would such imperfections also be a problem for who draws animation?

Do "eye safety" features that restrict the extreme blue frequencies mean that you would end up with color problems when copying slides or lighting something, or would they actually help against blue color casts/channel clipping?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, depends on the specific model but let me summarize.

1. The power output is much dimmer than those intended for photography. They are meant to be viewed directly. You are viewing the light source itself.
2. CRI is not important for them. Of course, you need to define if it is important to you.
3. Some side points are that you need to improvise a way to hold them in place as a light source.

---

We live in an era of options. If you want to go for a cheap alternative to a Led Panel, look for some DIY options. There is one on youtube that additionally recommends a specific stripe of LEDs with good CRI.

CRI can be somehow compensated using a Color chart, but a color chart itself is not cheap, so probably you are spending more trying to fix colors than the cost of a decent led light stripe.

I will try to post some examples of CRI of one panel for drawing and one Led light for video later.

Comment: Can you please clarify the sentence *"The power output is a heck dimmer than the intended for photography"*  What is *"heck dimmer"* and  and what does *"than the intended for photography"*  mean.  If i had to guess i would say it is supposed to read- The power output is much dimmer than those intended for photography.

Comment: Yeap, let me edit that part.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a color chart won't help with poor CRI, because frequencies which aren't there just aren't there

Comment: Poor CRI is different than horrendous CRI. So, some can be adjusted. Let me post the tests.